# Cause of stepped crack up and away from lintel

Tags: civil-engineering, masonry

What are the likely causes of a stepped crack up and away from the edge of a lintel? See the diagram below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the likely causes of a **stepped** crack **up and away** from the edge of a lintel?

Shearing causes stepped cracks and bending causes vertical cracks.

[image: Shear vs. Bending Cracking]

[image: Shear Cracking Remediation]

See: "[Diagonal Cracks in Brick Walls and Its Measures](https://gharpedia.com/diagonal-cracks-brick-walls/)" or "[HeliBar Remedial](https://www.helifix.co.uk/products/remedial-products/helibar-remedial/)" where the causes and methods for remediation are explained. Two different causes and means to prevent worsening of the problem.